# Espresso: How to check if an integer value in a recylerview's child view is greater that 4000

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I have a recyclerView in my app. I have 2 fields in it(image_view, price_text_view). The value of price_textview looks like Rs.8000. Now I wanted to keep scrolling until I find an item on the recyclerview whose price is more that Rs.4000(>4000). Can someone please help me with the matcher etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you whole code here but can give you some logic for implementing this.

this can be done by `For loop`. And using `ArrayList` or `Array` you are passing in your `Adapter`.

Now lets assume you are passing `Arralist` to your `Adapter` say "arrayLst". and from your qustion I assume you are using `ArrayList` with `HashMap`.

so your `ArraList` would be like.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

now do something like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i<arrayList.size; i++){
     if(Integer.valueOf(arraylist.get(i).get("prise_tag")) > 4000){
          yourlayoutManager.smoothScrollTo(i);
          break;     
     }
}
```

I hope this will help you somehow.

Comment: Will it work with Espesso ? I am using Espresso tool for automation.